# Any CSLA 4 downloadable sample applications?

Tags: csla

I am looking for a full web (MVC or WebForm sample application which is based on [CSLA 4.0](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet). Any ideas? I think its ProjectTracker sample is WinForm only and based on older vesion of CSLA.

Answer (score 7):

Mark's experience with CSLA seems to be quite outdated. Nearly every point he made is inaccurate. CSLA is for user's use-case scenarios. Especially data-binding to UI's.

1) Using the folder analogy is completely inappropriate. You can have a single business object act as both a parent and child if you so choose, just not the same instance of your business object. Lazy loading of children is completely supported as well.

2) The serialization overhead is no more than what RIA services does, as CSLA uses the DataContractSerializer to utlimately serialize objects. Additionally MobileFormatter has been updated to allow for custom serializers. Now binary is supported as well as the original xml. Ultimately it all still goes through the DataConstractSerializer.

3) You can create any kind of DataPortal replacement, including using JSON within your own custom DataPortal. And CSLA command objects support managed properties, so serialization works exactly the same way as business objects.

4) It's true there is no in-place merge, however, I've never found this to be a problem.

5) Subscribers never get serialized with the business object. If your DataPortal is only local, then the original object is sent(not serialized) and so any subscribers it has will naturally still be attached.

I have no problem leveraging CSLA in both Windows Form and Silverlight environments. For 95% of the business user use-cases CSLA brings a lot to the table.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.lhotka.net/cslacvs/viewvc.cgi/core/trunk/Samples/NET/cs/ProjectTracker/Mvc3UI/ is the MVC3 Part of the famous CSLA ProjectTracker sample. This might be the
one to learn from.

Rocky himself checked a change in just 2 days ago, so this is probably as Cutting edge
as you can get for an CSLA sample, from the author himself.

Here are instructions on pulling code from svn

http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/Repository.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My advice - do not use CSLA. I am going to quote my reply to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234/have-you-attended-the-csla-master-class:

> I have a two years experience with CSLA. In fact, when I started our
>   project I really did not want to write an entity framework from
>   scratch, something that was done in all of my previous jobs.
>
> So, I picked CSLA. As any entity framework, it has good and bad
>   points. I will list a few of the bad ones, because the good ones are
>   described in abundance on the CSLA related sites. So, the nays:
>
> - CSLA parent-child relationship does not support folder-file pattern, where files are children of the parent folder, but they are
>     also independent entities. In CSLA, children are integral part of the
>     parent, so you cannot, for instance, update/delete/add a single child
>     without updating the whole object tree. Forget about lazy loading of
>     children - no such thing. In short, if your data model represents a
>     folder-file like structure - do not use CSLA. We had to twist CSLA
>     arms to let it support this mode.
> - Huge overhead in terms of state. Define a business object with 3 properties. Now send it over wire using some http binding. Pay
>     attention to what gets transmitted. I know XML is not the best
>     serialization vehicle, but your 3 properties are translated to ~4KB of
>     XML. What does it include? Business rules and field data manager state
>     among others. Extremely bloated. We employ zip compression, but still
>     this is very disturbing.
> - Silverlight does not have normal serialization engine, so CSLA comes with a Mobile serialization, which is good if there is nothing
>     else. The thing is that there are other things - JSON and protocol
>     buffers, but CSLA is incompatible with these techniques. And Mobile
>     serialization, although it solves the problem, it is a real pain when
>     it comes to commands, because there you have to implement it manually
>     (unlike business objects, which support it automatically for each
>     managed property). Remember CArchive from MFC of 10 years ago? This is
>     it.
> - Saving an object does not merge the new state in-place, rather returns a new object. We had much problems in Silverlight with the
>     fact that every save replaces the object tree. So, we had to override
>     the CSLA default behavior and implement in-place save with all the
>     associated complexity of merging new state with the old one.
> - You quickly loose control over what is actually transmitted on the wire. For example, here is something I have discovered while examining
>     the CSLA source code. Serializing a business object also serializes
>     all the serializable subscribers to its PropertyChanged and
>     PropertyChanging events. So, when such an object is sent to the
>     server, it carries along with it all the serializable subscribers to
>     these events. From the mobile object philosophy this is fine - mobile
>     object simply preserves its living environment across the application
>     tiers. From the practical point of view I find this a disaster waiting
>     to happen. Needless to say that I have disabled this feature right on
>     the spot.
> - Looking back after 2 years working with CSLA I have came to a conclusion that many others already came to before - your server side
>     objects just not the same as your client side. Trying to pretend they
>     are yields a lot of grief later in the development.  And this is
>     probably the most important nay to CSLA. The concept of mobile objects
>     seems right at first, but as the project grows and the server and
>     client sides develop having the same object type on the server and
>     client becomes more of a liability rather than advantage - the
>     internet is full of discussions on the matter.
>
> Bottom line - I would not have used CSLA if I had the same
>   understanding as I do now back then when I have started the project.
>   CSLA gives you much stuff out of the box and I like DataPortal concept
>   very much, but I see that I could have done fine without them and be
>   in a better place now.
>
> These are my 2 cents.